# How to get starknet chainId using javascript

Tags: starknet

See https://docs.starknet.io/docs/Blocks/transactions/#chain-id

The example is written in python. How do I do the equivalent in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can grab all chain IDs from [Starknet.js](https://github.com/0xs34n/starknet.js)

```js
import { StarknetChainId } from "starknet/constants";

const alphaGoerliChainId = StarknetChainId.TESTNET;
const alphaGoerli2ChainId = StarknetChainId.TESTNET2;
const mainnetChainD = StarknetChainId.MAINNET;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { encodeShortString, decodeShortString } from "starknet/dist/utils/shortString";

const SN_LOCALHOST = encodeShortString("SN_LOCALHOST");
const SN_GOERLI = encodeShortString("SN_GOERLI");
const SN_MAIN = encodeShortString("SN_MAIN");
```

**Follow-up**:

When I run `int.from_bytes(b'SN_MAIN', byteorder="big", signed=False)` using python I get:

`23448594291968334`

When I run `encodeShortString('SN_MAIN')?` using starknet.js I get:

`0x534e5f4d41494e`

Why?

**Answer:** `hex(23448594291968334) = 0x534e5f4d41494e`

Answer (score 1):

From newer versions of `starknet` library, it's not possible to access to `StarknetChainId` as mentioned above, but you need to do like following:

```js
import { constants } from 'starknet';

const alphaGoerliChainId = constants.StarknetChainId.TESTNET;
const alphaGoerli2ChainId = constants.StarknetChainId.TESTNET2;
const mainnetChainD = constants.StarknetChainId.MAINNET;
```